# An error occurred while installing bindex (0.5.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

"An error occurred while installing bindex (0.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bindex -v '0.5.0'` succeeds before bundling."

when I hit bundle install and this error comes up with a message "In Gemfile:
  web-console was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
    bindex"

ruby version: 2.4.2

rails: 5.1.4

what should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

I have found my solution. I just change the Xcode command line tools path and it is starts working.

how to change Xcode command line tools path=>
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations, select preferred Xcode from the drop down of command line tools list.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this after installing Big Sur, `xcode-select --install` fixed it for me.